# pdfbox 2.0: Concise description/list of what each jar/tool is used for

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Newb pdfbox user question. I am not a java developer which is probably why I don't understand straight away. I can import the jars into my test tool and use them directly though which I why I want to use it.

I can't find a concise/bullet point list (if this is possible of when/where/how to use all the jars/files/tools included in the latest pdf box release (2.0):

https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x

I assume most would use "pdfbox-app-2.0.0.jar" but what are all the other various jars/files, etc use for?

I have googled and looked on the pdfbox site but do not see a breakdown or description anywhere.

pdfbox-2.0.0-src.zip - obviously source

pdfbox-app-2.0.0.jar  - main jar to use

preflight-app-2.0.0.jar  - not sure

debugger-app-2.0.0.jar   - not sure

pdfbox-2.0.0.jar - how does this differ from pdfbox-app-2.0.0.jar above?

fontbox-2.0.0.jar - not sure

preflight-2.0.0.jar - not sure

xmpbox-2.0.0.jar - not sure

pdfbox-tools-2.0.0.jar - command line tools i believe?

pdfbox-debugger-2.0.0.jar - not sure

Thanks for any help
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfbox-2.0.0-src.zip - obviously source. It has many examples too.

pdfbox-app-2.0.0.jar - stand alone application, has all you need (pdfbox, fontbox, tools, bouncycastle, logging)

preflight-app-2.0.0.jar - stand alone application for checking PDF/A-1b validity

debugger-app-2.0.0.jar - PDFDebugger stand alone application, shows the structure of PDF files

pdfbox-2.0.0.jar - This is the core of PDFBox only

fontbox-2.0.0.jar - This is the font related stuff, this is also used by other projects

preflight-2.0.0.jar - This is the core of the PDF/A-1b validator. If you use it from a program, you will also need pdfbox, fontbox and xmpbox.

xmpbox-2.0.0.jar - this allows to read and write [XMP data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) in PDF files.

pdfbox-tools-2.0.0.jar - this is a component that contains some helper tools, e.g. to write image files.

pdfbox-debugger-2.0.0.jar - this is the core of PDFDebugger, it will need pdfbox and fontbox to work.

So if you're just starting and don't use maven, the easiest way is to use pdfbox-app-2.0.0.jar as library. You may have to add jai_imageio.jar and a jbig2 decoder (these are not bundled due to their license), see at https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html .

If you use maven, then look here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html